# Ruby Selenium / Page Object Model - launching Browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, page-object-gem

I'm learning selenium web-driver with ruby and page object model. My test code is below:

When I run the test I get an error unable to locate element which is due to the page loading but not redirecting to the correct link. Usually I would use driver.gets but cant get it to work with page object model?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'page-object'




class ContactDemoQa
  include PageObject



text_field(:name, :css => '#wpcf7-f375-p28-o1 > form > p:nth-child(2) > span > input')
text_field(:email, :css => '#wpcf7-f375-p28-o1 > form > p:nth-child(3) > span > input')
text_field(:subject, :css => '#wpcf7-f375-p28-o1 > form > p:nth-child(4) > span > input')
text_area(:messages, :css => '#wpcf7-f375-p28-o1 > form > p:nth-child(5) > span > textarea')
  button(:send, :css => '#wpcf7-f375-p28-o1 > form > p:nth-child(6) > input')


  def contact_method(name, email, subject, message)

    self.name = name
    self.email = email
    self.subject = subject
    self.message = message
    send
  end
  browser = 'http://demoqa.com/contact/'
  browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
  contact_demo_qa = ContactDemoQa.new(browser)

  contact_demo_qa.contact_method 'rob', 'green@hotmail.co.uk', 'test', 'Yellow'

end
```

With Page object model are you meant to have Page objects and methods in one class and then call the method using code below in another class?

```
browser = 'http://demoqa.com/contact/'
  browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
  contact_demo_qa = ContactDemoQa.new(browser)

  contact_demo_qa.contact_method 'rob', 'green@hotmail.co.uk', 'test', 'Yellow'
```

Comment: Are you asking if those last 4 lines should be in the `ContactDemoQa` class or not? Or are you asking where `driver.get` would be called?

Comment: I am asking if the last 4 lines should be in another class yes. Also When I run this class noting happens as it doesn’t direct to the correct URL were the page objects are. I am missing the URL but I don’t no how to direct it to the correct URL using the page object model. Usually I use driver.gets(http) in java @JustinKo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong, the page object model means everything belongs to page, that mean the URL, Locator and the methods that execute on that page should be located inside the the PageObject class, a PageObject class mean a page that is visible in your UI.

In your implementation, the problem is you're putting things that not belong to page inside page (last 4 lines), it should run separately. Then the Contact page should like this:

```
#contact_page.rb

require 'page-object'

class ContactPage
  include PageObject

    text_field(:name, :css => '#wpcf7-f375-p28-o1 > form > p:nth-child(2) > span > input')
    text_field(:email, :css => '#wpcf7-f375-p28-o1 > form > p:nth-child(3) > span > input')
    text_field(:subject, :css => '#wpcf7-f375-p28-o1 > form > p:nth-child(4) > span > input')
    text_area(:messages, :css => '#wpcf7-f375-p28-o1 > form > p:nth-child(5) > span > textarea')
    button(:send, :css => '#wpcf7-f375-p28-o1 > form > p:nth-child(6) > input')

    page_url 'http://demoqa.com/contact/'

  def contact_method(name, email, subject, message)
    self.name = name
    self.email = email
    self.subject = subject
    self.message = message
    send
  end
end
```

The test executor should define like this:

```
#testdemo.rb

require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'page-object/page_factory'
require_relative 'contact_page.rb'

include PageObject::PageFactory

#--set up--
@browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
#----------

#test execution
visit(ContactPage)
on(ContactPage).contact_method('rob', 'green@hotmail.co.uk', 'test', 'Yellow')
```

Comment: So what is the point in this, how does it make it anymore reliable having the objects and methods in one class and then calling them with the test demo class. Do you have any other page object examples?